# Select tag appearance browser to browser

Tags: css

These are the screenshots of how my select tag appear in IE and Firefox:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

How to make it appear same in every browser?

The css code is:

```
select{
    width:10%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 13px 0px 14px 10px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    color:#333;
    margin-left: -7px;
}
```

UPDATE :
        This new customized select dropdown workded fine in mozilla and chrome 
         select#city {
        -webkit-appearance: none;  /*REMOVES DEFAULT CHROME & SAFARI STYLE*/
        -moz-appearance: none;  /*REMOVES DEFAULT FIREFOX STYLE*/

```
    color: #fff;
    border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
    font-size: 13px;
    /* padding For Mozilla*/ 
    padding: 15px 0px 14px 2px;
    /* padding for chrome */
    -webkit-padding-before:15px;
    -webkit-padding-end:0px;
    -webkit-padding-after:13px !important;
    -webkit-padding-start:5px;
    width: 10%;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: -7px !important;
    background: #0d98e8 url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/universal-icons-set-for-web-and-mobile/100/controls_0-12-512.png) no-repeat right center;
    background-size: 40px 37px; /*TO ACCOUNT FOR @2X IMAGE FOR RETINA */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

select#city  option {
    background-color:#fff;
    color:black;
}
select::-ms-expand{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Every browser handles input controls in its own way. You can still try making it consistent.

Comment: i did evrything possible (within my knowledge)

Comment: See my answer @Mps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said, there is no straight way of doing this and I will not recommend this. After getting a little help from [here](http://www.kevinfremon.com/create-a-custom-drop-down-list-using-just-css/), this is the only way I could figure out to make it look consistent across all browsers.

So what I did,

1) I removed all existing styles

```
select::-ms-expand{
   display:none;  //FOR IE
}
select.custom-dropdown {
  -webkit-appearance: none;  /*REMOVES DEFAULT CHROME & SAFARI STYLE*/
  -moz-appearance: none;  /*REMOVES DEFAULT FIREFOX STYLE*/
  border: 0 !important;  /*REMOVES BORDER*/
}
```

2) Applied custom styles to `select`

```
color: #fff;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 font-size: 14px;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 35%;
 cursor: pointer;

 background: #0d98e8 url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/universal-icons-set-for-web-and-mobile/100/controls_0-12-512.png) no-repeat right center;
 background-size: 40px 37px; /*TO ACCOUNT FOR @2X IMAGE FOR RETINA */
```

3) Applied new styles on `option`

```
select.custom-dropdown option {
  background-color:#fff;
  color:black;
}
```

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/3qvuhux5/2/) the fiddle of my attempt.

See if this is what you want.

Comment: The Padding is what changing browser to browser..is there any way to apply different paddiing for different browser to browser like using browser agent

Comment: Yes you can, but then if you are thinking to give different styles for different elements in different browser. It might get difficult to manage everything

Comment: well actually i have only one dropdown and its in menu and i'm using it in evry page. So May be using the browser agent only for dropdown padding will solve my problem..thank you for your replies

Comment: Sure then, go ahead